# Assigning to nsarray strong form incompitable void

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
youtubeManager *ym=[[youtubeManager alloc] init];

NSArray *ns=[[NSArray alloc]init];

ns=[ym receivedGroupsJSON:data];//Showing error in this line


- (NSArray *)receivedGroupsJSON:(NSData *)objectNotation
{

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *groups = [youtubemodelbuilder groupsFromJSON:objectNotation error:&error];

   return groups;
}
```

***Assigning to NSArray strong form incompatible void***

Comment: Assigning to NSArray *_strong form incompatible void

Comment: The error says, you are about to assigning the empty stuff.

Comment: there are possibilities for the many way in the code. By seeing this code. Can't judge the solution

Comment: Why aren't you checking if the array is nil and then checking the NSError value?

Answer (score 2):

`ns` is declared as an NSArray, but the compiler thinks `[ym receivedGroupsJSON:data]` will return `void`.

You have shown a method indicating it returns an NSArray.

Either

1. In this class' header file (@interface), you declare the same method as returning a `void`, or
2. You have another identically named method in another class, which `ym` points to, that returns a void.

Also, the first of these two lines is pointless:

```
NSArray *ns=[[NSArray alloc]init];
ns=[ym receivedGroupsJSON:data];//Showing error in this line
```

Because you're creating a new NSArray, making `ns` point to it, and then on the next line, you're making `ns` point to a totally different NSArray.  Just replace this whole thing with:

```
NSArray *ns;
ns=[ym receivedGroupsJSON:data];//Showing error in this line
```

Or even simpler:

```
NSArray *ns = [ym receivedGroupsJSON:data];
```